# make file - ignoring .c files in prerequisites for implicit rules

Tags: makefile

I am learning make from GNU documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overview .

(1) I am confused on which .c files we can omit when specifying the prerequisites for a target which has an implicit rule. For eg:

```
ex: books.o
    cc -o ex books.o

books.o : hello.c hello.h books.c books.h lib.c
    cc -c hello.c books.c lib.c
```

In the above example can I ignore the recipe (make it implicit) for the target books.o , i.e. can I write

```
books.o : hello.h books.h
```

even though there is no lib.c?

(2) The documentation didn't mention (so far) what is 'cc'? Is it 'gcc'?

Comment: In your example you are compiling three source files into one object file. That is legal, but there is seldom a good reason for it. How do you feel about compiling `hello.c`, `books.c` and `lib.c` into `hello.o`, `books.o` and `lib.o`, respectively?

Comment: `cc` is the POSIX-standard name for the C compiler on your system.  That C compiler implementation might be GCC, or Clang, or Intel's C compiler, or whatever.  Whatever C compiler you have installed, `cc` is the default name that will run it.  You can also run it using the specific name for the compiler, like `gcc` or `clang` or whatever.

Comment: @MadScientist: I stand corrected.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't be so definitive.  `cc` will point to the default C compiler on the system.  If you install a different compiler than that, it's not necessarily true that`cc` will be reset to point to that one.